# What could cause intermittent flickering in a RGBIC LED Strip?

Tags: circuit-design, short-circuit, rgb

I have a 5m RGBIC LED Strip ([specifically this one](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/product/B093PRYW1D?th=1)), cut and connected ([using this set](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/product/B09L82NP7G)) with wires of less than 1.5m length in total. Generally everthing seems to be fine. Colour, brightness, segments all react as I would expect them to.

But occasionally it flickers. Specifically, it seems to be turning everything to blue for just a millisecond or so, then back to normal. As far as I can tell (it is happening quite fast) this happens along the entire length and is not restricted to one or several segments.

EDIT: I should clarify that I am not certain on the error pattern. It is not very frequent and I have no way of reliably reproducing it. Consequently, I have never observed it while looking at the LED strip directly. I *think* it turns all blue, but it is possible that only some LEDs turn blue and simply drown out the orange it is normaly at.

I have tried swapping out the power supply, but it happened with both. Either should have been fine, with both supplying 12V and rated for 18W/36W. Even on maximum brightness the strip does not draw more than 7W.

The connections seem to be fine too, as I cannot provoke the effect by moving them or the cables / strip going into them.

Any idea what could be causing this / what I can investigate would be appreciated.

Comment: If all LEDs go blue, the controller box must send such data out. Maybe it is a badly designed product, or it gets too noisy power from power supply, receives noise from IR/RF/buttons and spends a moment figuring out if it was a valid command, or the extension cable causes EMC problems. Get a scope or logic analyzer and investigate if the controller really sends out data for all LEDs to go blue for a moment.

Comment: Does the controller have a user manual with any diagnostic information? Perhaps blue is the default color when the controller resets due to a fault. Without some design information like the controller or LED strip schematic it would be difficult to troubleshoot from a hardware perspective.  Best idea may be to post a question on the Amazon pages that you have linked to and possibly other users have seen this problem and know of a solution.

Comment: i've seen this. ALL blue is a signal with a bunch of zeros, so the likely problem is that your high data signal isn't crossing the voltage threshold. Add capacitors to +/- on both ends of the strip, which will help keep the gnd rail from getting pulled up (and the v+ rail down, but that doesn't matter much), something 16v or greater and size of 100uf-1000uf. By keeping the gnd rail at absolute zero relative to both the led power and the data+ signal, you effectively raise the signal voltage. You might also want to try running them at 9v instead of 12.

Comment: @Justme Would that be something like this: https://www.saleae.com?

Comment: @Nedd I'll try that, thanks.

Comment: @dandavis I'm afraid that goes somewhat over my head. I'll try to read into it, but that might take me a moment.

Comment: I should clarify that I am not certain that it is really turning everything blue, neither on the everything part nor on the blue part. It looks like it, but is is very fast. Also, I have never been able to observe the error while looking at the strip directly, since it does not happen reliably and there are only so many hours I can keep staring at a LED strip.

Comment: Putting a big electrolytic capacitor on a system with ~100 nanosecond rise times is not going to do much for signal integrity. An oscilloscope could let you rule out signal problems, but this sounds like the controller itself glitching.

Comment: @user1850479 You put the cap on the rails, not the signal. If you meter 10v at the end of a long 12v strip, you might think it's dropped 2v, but actually your high rail will be at 11v compared to source, and your ground will be at 1v compared to source. The data line has no drop as it has virtually no load, and if your signal starts at 3.3v absolutely, it will be 2.3v relatively at the end of the strip, which might not be high enough to be considered high. This is most often noticeable when transitioning a large run of pixel from light to dark.

Comment: @dandavis I understand where the capacitor goes.  My point is that it does nothing in this circuit.  You cannot cancel out a DC ohmic loss with a capacitor.  If you have 1 V of drop on a 12V input, and you add a capacitor it simply charges up to 11V.  The reason people think doing that will help is that they think the electrolytic will provide decoupling of AC current induced onto the power lines, which is incorrect given the rise time of the signal lines (~100ns).

Comment: @user1850479: If it does nothing, why did the cap solve the "1 blue frame in the middle of an animation" problem on a couple of my strips, most pronouncedly the dense 144/m strips where coupling is less of an issue? I'm open to new explanations.

Comment: @dandavis I don't know what problem you had or what you did, but I can tell you with absolute certainty that you did not use a capacitor to decrease DC voltage drop in a wire because that is not a thing that capacitors can do. The usual theory people have for large electrolytic capacitors is that they'll provide decoupling, but that really isn't the case given the rise times involved. Also, it's "decoupling", and that doesn't have any relationship to the number of diodes or their density.